# Como popular uma lista ao DTO de forma mais simples

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Para mostrar a lista de um cadastro no meu sistema, eu populo a consulta em um DTO conforme abaixo. Minha pergunta é: Existe uma forma mais simples de popular a consulta na lista do DTO?

```
public List<ObjetoDTO> find(Query query) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object[]> queryResult = query.getResultList();
    List<ObjetoDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if (queryResult.isEmpty() == false) {
        for (Object[] item : queryResult) {
            ObjetoDTO dto = new ObjetoDTO();
            dto.setId((Integer) item[0]);
            dto.setTitulo((String) (item[1]));
            dto.setDescricao((String) (item[2]));
            list.add(dto);
        }
    }
    return list;
 }
```

Comment: qual a versão do JPA?

Comment: Desculpa, estou usando Hibernate 5.4.16.Final, não consegui identificar qual versão JPA o Hibernate usa :/

Comment: já tentou assim: `List<ObjetoDTO> list = (List<ObjetoDTO>) query.getResultList();`?

Comment: Neste caso, tive um erro de java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id". Pois meu id é um Integer.

Comment: No banco está como ? o campo `id`? ´porque a linha que eu te passei vi em varios forum que funciona!

Comment: Vc pode fazer a própria query já retornar o DTO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934668

Comment: No banco está como id SERIAL NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode tentar usar o dozer!

Baixe a dependência se o seu projeto for em maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
    <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
ObjetoDto dto = mapper.map(queryResult, ObjetoDto.class);
```

So que no caso quando eu usei eu criei as classes Dtos, eu tinha as entidades e dos Dtos, entao eu passava o `mapper.map(entidade.class, ObjetoDto.class);`

Para maiores detalhes, visite o site deles  http://dozer.sourceforge.net/